# KVM: Is it possible to detect guest disk was mounted RW?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, filesystems, ext4

Let's assume I have a KVM-based virtual machine.
There is a volume that contains the operating system and the data.

I know it is possible to access from host at least READ-ONLY the filesystem which is on guest.

If it is possible to access the guest FS in RW mode, then could I somehow detect that the filesystem was mounted?

The filesystem is ext4, is it storing any information about how and when it was mounted?

Comment: Just the dirty bit.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I would have expected that to work. But when I verified with `tune2fs` on a file system definitely mounted rw, I saw this: `Filesystem state:         clean`. I think that's because that bit has a different meaning when journaling is in use.

Comment: LVM track usage of partition with "o" flag in lvs command.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things **LV Write Access  read/write** and **# open  2** first one is disk is open as read/write and second one is open count.

$ lvdisplay -v /dev/vg_root/lv_swap
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg_root/lv_swap
  LV Name                lv_swap
  VG Name                vg_root
  LV UUID                SyLfHM-iiKk-Kkxn-O6r9-6DaV-kTFI-7Uvzpb
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2019-04-12 14:47:37 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                1.00 GiB
  Current LE             256
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:1